# LitElement & Google PageSpeed Insights

Tags: polymer, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, lit-element, pagespeed-insights

Relatively new user to LitElement here. Everything I have read said it's "lightning-fast" and the future on the web, right?

As a user who is trying to build a corporate website with it, we are having some real difficulties with scoring high on PageSpeed Insights while still using our custom webcomponents, and eliminating FOUC.

Every website I can find that is using LitElement has a **terrible** PageSpeed score. I am talking single digits in some cases. It seems crazy to me that Google being the owner of both Pagespeed/Search & LitElement has a technology that clashes with each other in this way...?

I'm wondering if anyone has any personal success to share, or has read any material online, that shares best practices for a) dealing with webcomponents/FOUC while b) scoring high on PageSpeed?

Comment: care to share a few example sites? it is hard to say why it is slow without seeing what PSI is complaining about. A lot of it could be down to implementation given that web components are a "new" technology, the one example i did find loaded 27 scripts to render 3 links so my guess is the problem starts as part of building the component. Beyond that standard practices such as inlining critical CSS, minimising files, image format choice etc. all contribute and are normally independent of technology (although whether you can inline CSS when everything is rendered via JS is another question)

Comment: Please, add substantive information including a link to the project and the other projects where the performance you experience it as you say "terrible". We're happy to take a look and see what this means.

Comment: Sure, thanks jimmont and Graham. So my project is not published yet, as we try to work out some of these details... but let me try to provide more details.


So the biggest thing right now is dealing with FOUC, and particularly layout shift in PSI. If I move my webcomponent js to the head tags, it reduces the FOUC, but then PSI complains about render blocking JS.


Just for an example, I know every site is going to be different, but ea.com appears to be using litelement and they have a very poor PSI score.

Comment: this question is too ambiguous to answer, it's like asking why is it so bright outside when we have no idea where on the planet you're located let alone how bright it is--could be on a glacier or ocean somewhere at noon or in a cave when a flashlight shines in through a crack in the rocks during the middle of the new moon night; probably an import sequence issue and poor page building strategy, try the Lighthouse chrome devtools features for hands-on insights